# Is it possible to use a canvas app with the community guest user?

Tags: community, integration, canvas

I have a canvas app that I would like to expose on a customer community that would query data on behalf of the user. I would like for this page to be available on the public facing pages and use the "guest user"'s access to query data.

I enabled the canvas app for the user's profile but when I look at the page, the canvas component completely collapses.

Is this possible and if not are there any workarounds for an external app to communicate with the community page?

Comment: I'm attempting to do something similar, but on a visualforce page in a community. I'd like that canvas app on the visualforce page to be accessible to the guest user, but it always shows "You don't have permissions to view application with namespace [] and api name ___". Not sure if I'm mis-configuring something or it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in order to use Canvas you need to have an active session ID. Since guest users aren't logging in, they don't have that Session ID. It apparently used to be possible to manually set the ID, but Salesforce has since disabled that.

Something strange that I noticed is that if you are logged into internal Salesforce and you Login to the community as a contact, it will authenticate you in the canvas app as your original internal user.

My workaround to achieve the functionality that I was looking for was to use an iframe that passed parameters into the URL and had links inside of the iframe back to the internal community that passed back parameters in that URL.